# PHP Curl - Empty Reply from server

Tags: php, apache, curl

I have an application which calls RESTful API using CURL POST request. The request is giving desired response if POSTFIELD data is of smaller size (<1024 bytes) but in case of large POSTFIELD the CURL execution only returns "Empty reply from server" error. API script does get executed as I can see only see partial data inserted in my database post which execution terminates abruptly.

I have already tried increasing default_session_timeout and memory_limit.

I checked Apache error logs but did not find anything logged in there as well. This is my code to consume REST API using CURL:

```
                $curl = curl_init($this->serviceUrl);
                $curl_post_data = (is_array($data)) ? http_build_query($data) : $data;
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 420); 
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
                $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

                if ($curl_response === false) {
                    $errorMessage = curl_error($curl);
                    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                    \Tools::writeErrorLog($errorMessage);
                    \Tools::writeErrorLog($info);
                }

                curl_close($curl);
                return $curl_response;
```

Is there any specific fix for this either in server configuration or the PHP code itself?

PHPINFO Details:

- POST_MAX_SIZE - 8MB
- Memory Limit - 256 MB
- DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT - 60

Comment: An empty reply is not a problem of curl itself. A http server should never reply with an empty response. It has to be broken or something. Could you please give more details about the other service? Is there perhaps some firewall which blocks your request?

Comment: Look into curl_getinfo for http_code http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: @Timm It is under a firewall, however smaller posts do get processed and also in case of a larger POSTs partial data does get processed by the API. Also, the API and application are hosted on the same server (Application architecture itself is that way!), so this should not be a firewall issue.

Comment: @Mihai The curl-getinfo response : [content_type] =>
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 1339
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 8.03231
[namelookup_time] => 0.000262
[connect_time] => 0.000958
[pretransfer_time] => 0.019984
[size_upload] => 830166
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 103353
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => 830166
[starttransfer_time] => 0.021911
[redirect_time] => 0

Comment: @Harsh could you try `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);` and see if it outputs a message? What does `curl_error` say?

Comment: @Timm curl_error gives "Empty Reply from Server" message. I ll try the failonerror piece.

Comment: @Timm I already have that option set. But it is not solving my issue. I am not able to figure out the sudden termination of curl_exec. I suspected memory leak and in order to overcome that I tried to increase memory_limit upto 4096M but that is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. Problem was of memory leak as  I suspected. I revisited my API code and unset some unnecessary objects which freed memory for further process. @Timm and @Mihai Thanks for your help!!

Comment: So POST size has a limit in CURL?